# Questions on localization/globalization of Ctype & .ToString

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization, globalization, aspose

A few questions I need answered to help debug an issue I'm having with globalization/localization that's leaving me rather stumped.

**1)** How exactly does `CType` work if I convert a string into a double when it comes to globalization/localization?

From my research, and asking other developers in the office, I think CType should use whatever culture settings you have on your computer. So for example `CType("1.23", Double)` would work fine for a US culture computer. But it would mess up by converting it to `123` on say a Netherland's culture computer where `,` is recognized as the decimal point and `.` is recognized as the thousand separator. But if the string was `1,23`, then it would work fine on the Netherlands computer and become `123` on the US computer.

**2)** How does `.ToString` work if I grab a number and say `doubleNumber.ToString` to convert it to a string?

From my experience here, I'm 99.9% sure that there should be no thousand separators included, so a number like `1,234.56` would be turned into `1234.56` on a US computer, correct? And on a Netherlands culture computer that number would become `1234,56` because `,` is the decimal place, right?

**3)** Is there a way on a Netherlands culture computer that `CType(#, Double)` or `.ToString` on a double could somehow mess up and start recognizing `.` as the decimal separator instead of a `,` like Netherland culture is supposed to recognize?

**Bottom Line:** Item #3 is where I'm having my problem. 99.9% of my users, US and foreign, can run my software fine without any localization issues. But a user in the Netherlands reported a bug where importing a number from a `txt` file somehow was converting `1,23` into `123`. When one of our customer support people told them to change the decimal point to a `.` it worked fine. Short of that Netherlands user for some reason using a US culture computer (which they insist they were not) I can't figure out how this issue is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your assumptions. .NET will use the culture of the current computer.

The way to apply a specific culture is:

```
Dim str As String = "97.9"
Dim num As Double = Double.Parse(str, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And the same to convert a number to string:

```
num = 97.9
str = num.ToString(Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You can specify the needed culture, see this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The framework will use the current culture of the current thread as a default if no other is provided. One would normally set the proper culture info in either:

1) the application entry point method:

```
<STAThread()>
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.Run(New Form1)
End Sub
```

2) the constructor of your main form:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("nb-NO")
End Sub
```

You can of course set the culture info explicit whenever a member have an IFormatProvider parameter:

```
1.2R.ToString(New CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Output: 1.2

```
1.2R.ToString(New CultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

Output: 1,2