# Peso Sign Format in DataGridViewCell?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need my DG's second column to have "Php" (Philippine Peso) which is the DG is bound in a table, and the field set to "Currency". I've tried a lot of Googling for this but they just don't work. Also something about the "CultureInfo" is really not clear to me. I just use this and have a dollar sign.

```
 DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"
```

Can someone teach me some possible ways how to have Php Currency?

I also tried this just in case a miracle happens lol.

```
  DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "fil-PH"
```

Any help and ideas greatly appreciated!

P.S.

I transferred this project in my laptop and it successfully shows *"Php"*. Maybe it has something to do with manufacturing history already.

Newbie coder here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the correct [currency format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) which is uppercase `C`.

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
```

Then you need the correct [culture info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-PH")
```

You can also assign a thread specific culture info. See my answer in this post:

[Questions on localization/globalization of Ctype & .ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064176/1842065)

Comment: Wow it's that easy! I've been trying to solve this for 2 months now! Thanks a-many! And also for the reference! Cheers! :D